# How to apply CSS coloring to this flask template?

Tags: html, css, flask

I am using flask to serve a html service. In this piece of code below:

```
{% if terms|length > 1 %}
    <div class="term">
    {% for term in terms %}
        {{ term }} &nbsp;&nbsp;
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

`terms` is originally a simple list of items `['a', 'b', 'c']`.

The current `div class="term"` tag add the same background color to each term as it iterates the values. Now, the terms become a list of tuple with values like the following:

```
('a': 1)
('b': 2)
('c': 3)
```

I want to add different colors to `a`, `b`, `c` based on its values: `1`, `2`, `3`. `1` gives one color, `2` gives another color and `3` another color too.

The current stylesheet has one entry:

```
div.term {
    background-color:mintcream;
}
```

How can I achieve this effect with HTML and CSS?

EDIT: Per suggestion, new CSS definition:

```
div.term.term-count-0 {
    background-color:coral;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define three css

```
div.term.term-count-1 {
    background-color:coral;
}

div.term.term-count-2 {
    background-color:red;
}

div.term.term-count-3 {
    background-color:black;
}
```

You can then use the following code:

```
{% if terms|length > 1 %}

    {% for term, n in terms %}
        <div class="term.term-count-{%n%}">
        {{ term }} &nbsp;&nbsp;
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```